# celery received tasks and execute it step by step (Singleton)

Tags: django, celery

in my Django project with celery, I have celery task function that needs to be received all incoming tasks but starts it step by step like Singleton.

I can do this like:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def make_some_task(self, event_id):
    lock_name = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'create_lock')
    is_exists = os.path.exists(lock_name)
    while is_exists:
        time.sleep(10)

    with open('create_lock', 'w') as file:
        file.write('locked')

    ..... do some staff.....

   os.remove(lock_name)
```

but I think this is not the correct way to use this inside Celery, I think must be the better way to implement this

Comment: If you want to some tasks to be executed one by one then you don't need the task you mentioned in the code. Celery already works on queue based system so it will execute the tasks one by one

Comment: it will execute the tasks one by one if you have 1 worker and only one main thread, I have 4 workers and more than one threads, and I need some celery functions works on all workers and one celery function as the Singleton

Comment: have you considered using group http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Comment: is_exists = os.path.exists(lock_name)
while is_exists:
        time.sleep(10)

is_exists value will never change here.

Comment: this value will be False for current thread task
but for other will be True, until this thread realize it

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html